# Import Double Quotes Qualified CSV File With BULK INSERT Not Working

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Data_NEW FROM 'D:\Data.csv' 
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='","',ROWTERMINATOR ='"\n"',FirstRow=1);
```

I'm having trouble to run bulk insert with a double quoted csv file. Could you please help me out on this one.

csv file has the following:

> "Device","Pat
>   Device","Server","Location","Time","Value","Units","Status"
>   "101.162.57.198- Slave56","localhost ( Data Center )","Output
>   True","","Nov 14, 2017 14:58:00","88.8","kW","" "101.162.57.198-
>   Slave56","localhost ( Data Center )","Output True","","Nov 14, 2017
>   16:58:00","88.7","kW","" "101.162.57.198- Slave56","localhost ( Data
>   Center )","Output True","","Nov 14, 2017 18:58:00","88.5","kW",""
>   "101.162.57.198- Slave56","localhost ( Data Center )","Output
>   True","","Nov 14, 2017 20:58:00","89.0","kW",""

Comment: What is the problem? Are there any errors?

Comment: Please provide us an error , it will be more useful for us.

Comment: Do you have to import the file using Bulk Insert? If not you should consider using Powershell do that you can use .net objects to import and validate the data. https://www.fpweb.net/blog/powershell-tips-working-with-csv-files/

Comment: that blog post is 404ed

Answer (score 0):

1. You should either set `FirstRow=2` or delete the first row from your csv-file
2. Change your row terminator to be like this: `ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'`
3. You should delete the first and the last double quotes in each row of your csv-file.

**Upd:**
Try to use `'0x0a'` instead of `'\n'` as a row terminator. 
If the action doesn't solve the problem, create a format file to describe exact relations between table's and csv-file's columns. Links below  will help you:

[Non-XML Format Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server)

[Create a Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server)

Then use this command:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Data_NEW FROM 'D:\Data.csv' 
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'D:\yourFMT.fmt');
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes. Still getting error:"Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 8. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly."

Comment: Which is datatype of the field "Status" in the table dbo.Data_NEW?

Comment: Status varchar(250)